# Is there a keyboard shortcut to show/open the Trash?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, automation

I know how to create custom shortcuts with scripting, but I want to know if there's a built-in shortcut. To clarify, this is to *show* the Trash, not to empty it.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the Trash?

Comment: In the Terminal, type `open ~/.Trash`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using a [Spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29) or a program such as [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28software%29) that allows you configure keyboard shortcuts to perform actions. Here is a solution, create an AppleScript run only Application that will open the trash can for you. Its not a built in command but is should fit the bill nicely and you can do it all with built it tools.

1. Open AppleScript Editor
2. Open a new script editor window if one did not already open.
3. Enter the follow in to the blank editor window

   ```
   tell application "Finder"
       open trash    
   end tell
   ```
4. Test the script, press Run, trash should open.
5. Save the Script with the name "OpenTrash" make sure to select "**File Format:**" ***Application*** and **check** the "**Run Only**" option.
6. Open the newly saved OpenTrash Application, trash can contents should open in the Finder.

Introduce it to your favorite program launcher, and set up keyboard shortcuts etc. Also note that spotlight should index it as well and you can use that to open the Trash can now too.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>  and then search for "Tr"... Then press <kbd>enter</kbd>  once "OpenTrash" is highlighted.

Comment: you can even assign an icon to the new "trash" app, very nice, best solution

Comment: using this technique (had to remind myself how to change the icon of a file - https://web.archive.org/web/20151012191226/https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13922?locale=en_US

Answer (score 5):

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) there is no native shortcut to open Trash.

Comment: That page is missing some shortcuts, and it doesn't specifically say that there's no shortcut for opening the trash.

Answer (score 3):

A very poor man's solution would be to just use <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> in Finder to open `~/.Trash`.

Comment: I hate touching my trackpad if I can avoid it, but I'm not about to type eleven characters just to avoid clicking on the dock.

Comment: This is the way for me. Tilde dot slash T completes and I do this so seldom, it’s not worth the effort to drop an AppleScript but to each their own workflow, I suppose… @MichaelDorst

Answer (score 0):

@MrDaniel thank you so much, that worked great. I didn't see the option for **Run Only** to select, but it still works in 2022.

I followed the steps from that post, plus I added my own notes/steps, including adding an icon image and adding a shortcut in Finder.

- Open Script Editor.app
- Type:

```
tell application "Finder"
     open trash    
end tell
```

- Create/name a folder Scripts
- Save As OpenTrash.scpt and save to Scripts folder
- Save As OpenTrash.app; File format: Application and save to Desktop
  **Note**: I don’t see an option to set as ‘Run Only’ per original post from MrDaniel from 10 years ago
- Open **System Preferences** > **Dock and Menu Bar**
- Set **Dock** to Large size
- Uncheck **Automatically hide and show the Dock**
- Screenshot the Trash from the Dock
- Go back to **System Preferences** > **Dock and Menu Bar**
- Set **Dock** to Small size
- Check **Automatically hide and show the Dock**
- Right-click the screenshot on the Desktop
- Click the OpenTrash.app to select it then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Click the top left icon
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- The Trash image now displays for OpenTrash.app
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> the desktop screenshot
- Open **Finder**
- Press and hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and drag OpenTrash.app from the desktop (or wherever you saved it) to the top of the Finder window
- Click the Trash icon at the top of the Finder window
- Another Finder window opens for the Trash
- Close both finder windows
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > type "OpenTrash"
- OpenTrash.app with the Trash icon displays & OpenTrash.scpt with the page icon displays
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> & OpenTrash.app will open the Trash folder

Info/Question: I've noticed if I have another Finder window already open I have to then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to that folder.  Does anyone know what needs to be added to the script for something like 'bring folder to the front'?

Answer (score 0):

[LaunchBar has this built in](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) - macOS does not.

[image: Open Trash action in LaunchBar app for macOS]

Type OT and select the action, a feature of this app is self-training easily to shortcuts of your typing.